# MEAN Stack: How to update a function's result to the database?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm having a commenting system and I need to store the upvotes in the database whenever the upvote icon is clicked. The function I have increases the number but as soon as I refresh it, it says 0 again. How do I store it directly to the database?
Here is the code:

In the **ang.js** in the *public/javascripts* directory:

```
var app=angular.module('peopleComments',['ui.router']);
app.factory('comments',['$http', function($http){
var c={
comments:[]
};

//loading all existing comments with getAll()
c.getAll=function(){
return $http.get('/comments').success(function(data){
    angular.copy(data, c.comments);
});
};

//function which creates the new comments for updating in the database
c.create = function(comment) {
return $http.post('/comments', comment).success(function(data){
c.comments.push(data);
});};
return c;
}]);

app.controller('Base',[
'$scope','comments',function($scope,comments){
  $scope.comments=comments.comments;

    $scope.addComment=function(){
        if(!$scope.username||$scope.username==''){$scope.username='Anonymous';}
        if(!$scope.contents||$scope.contents==''){return;}
        comments.create({
            username: $scope.username,
            contents: $scope.contents,
            });
        $scope.username='';
        $scope.contents='';
    }
$scope.increaseUpvotes=function(comment){   //function which updates the upvotes
  comment.upvotes+=1;
}

}]);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is updating your database? Or just a variable in your browser

Comment: The comments are getting updated, but the upvotes are not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `c.update(comment)` method in your service that takes a comment to update and then calls a corresponding `$http.put()` method in your API to update the comment when the upvote button is clicked.

**Update**: One more potential issue - if you are not specifically creating a `comment.upvotes` property and setting it to 0 by default then your `comment.upvotes += 1` might be adding one to `null` or `undefined` and not really adding one.